# Maven (with tycho) fails while materialize-products

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have an RCP Application which builds find on Eclipse 4.5.2 and 4.6.3; Today i tried to upgrade to Eclipse 2019-6;
when i try to manfest a product with maven (mvn clean install)

i get the following output:

```
[INFO] --- tycho-p2-repository-plugin:1.4.0:archive-repository (default-archive-repository) @ at.biooffice.rcp.product ---
[INFO] Building zip: D:\WS18\git\at.biooffice.rcp.product\target\at.biooffice.rcp.product-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-p2-director-plugin:1.4.0:materialize-products (materialize-products) @ at.biooffice.rcp.product ---
[INFO] Installing product at.biooffice for environment win32/win32/x86_64 to D:\WS18\git\at.biooffice.rcp.product\target\products\at.biooffice\win32\win32\x86_64
Installing at.biooffice 3.0.1.201907011447.
Installation failed.
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
        Software being installed: BioOffice 3.0.1.201907011447 (at.biooffice 3.0.1.201907011447)
        Missing requirement: toolingwin32.win32.x86_64org.eclipse.equinox.ds 3.0.1.201907011447 requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.equinox.ds 1.6.0.v20190122-0806' but it could not be found
        Cannot satisfy dependency:
                From: BioOffice 3.0.1.201907011447 (at.biooffice 3.0.1.201907011447)
                To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; toolingat.biooffice.configuration [3.0.1.201907011447,3.0.1.201907011447]
        Cannot satisfy dependency:
                From: toolingat.biooffice.configuration 3.0.1.201907011447
                To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; toolingwin32.win32.x86_64org.eclipse.equinox.ds [3.0.1.201907011447,3.0.1.201907011447]
There were errors. See log file: D:\WS18\git\at.biooffice.parent\workspace\.metadata\.log
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] BioOffice 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ........................... SUCCESS [  2.483 s]
[INFO] microsoftsqlserver 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT .................. SUCCESS [  0.590 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.gemini.dbaccess.microsoftsqlserver 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  0.869 s]
[INFO] com.mysql.jdbc 5.1.38-SNAPSHOT ..................... SUCCESS [  0.170 s]
[INFO] org.eclipse.gemini.dbaccess.mysql 5.1.38-SNAPSHOT .. SUCCESS [  0.298 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.osgi.service.dialog 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .... SUCCESS [  0.269 s]
[INFO] lumo.osgi.service.notification 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ...... SUCCESS [  0.457 s]
[INFO] lumo.osgi.service.notification.impl 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT . SUCCESS [  0.471 s]
[INFO] lumo.core.runtime 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ................... SUCCESS [ 18.182 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.osgi.service.eclipselink 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  2.032 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.rcp 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .................... SUCCESS [  2.129 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.osgi.service.eclipselink.impl 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  2.474 s]
[INFO] lumo.exports.csv 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .................... SUCCESS [  1.399 s]
[INFO] lumo.exports.mssql 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .................. SUCCESS [  1.387 s]
[INFO] lumo.exports.kml 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .................... SUCCESS [  1.365 s]
[INFO] lumo.exports.shp 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .................... SUCCESS [  1.209 s]
[INFO] lumo.exports.vcard 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .................. SUCCESS [  1.260 s]
[INFO] lumo.exports.taxaendangered 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ......... SUCCESS [  1.276 s]
[INFO] lumo.imports.xml.nls 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ................ SUCCESS [  1.272 s]
[INFO] lumo.osgi.service.multimedia 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ........ SUCCESS [  1.254 s]
[INFO] lumo.osgi.service.multimedia.impl 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ... SUCCESS [  1.380 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.osgi.service.dialog.impl 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  1.540 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.update 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ................. SUCCESS [  1.262 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.osgi.service.map 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ....... SUCCESS [  1.224 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.osgi.service.map.impl 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .. SUCCESS [  1.537 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.attachedliterature 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  1.365 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.bioobject 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ........ SUCCESS [  1.399 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.common.admin 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ........... SUCCESS [  1.278 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.collection 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ....... SUCCESS [  1.266 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.contact 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .......... SUCCESS [  1.281 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.determination 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .... SUCCESS [  1.265 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.dataexchange 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ..... SUCCESS [  3.052 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.excursion 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ........ SUCCESS [  1.257 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.literature 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ....... SUCCESS [  1.263 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.lookups 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .......... SUCCESS [  1.326 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.multimedia 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ....... SUCCESS [  1.329 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.report 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ........... SUCCESS [  2.193 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.nls 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .............. SUCCESS [  1.284 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.project 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .......... SUCCESS [  1.279 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.querymanager 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ..... SUCCESS [  1.798 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.site 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ............. SUCCESS [  1.313 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.taxon 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ............ SUCCESS [  1.601 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.welcome 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .......... SUCCESS [  1.339 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.loan 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ............. SUCCESS [  1.375 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.views.servicemonitor 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ... SUCCESS [  1.235 s]
[INFO] jre.win32.win32.x86_64 8.0.66 ...................... SUCCESS [  2.631 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.feature 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ................ SUCCESS [  0.967 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.feature.admin 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .......... SUCCESS [  0.226 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.feature.free.addons 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT .... SUCCESS [  0.275 s]
[INFO] at.biooffice.rcp.product 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT ............ FAILURE [ 37.278 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  07:01 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-01T16:54:21+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:1.4.0:materialize-products (materialize-products) on project at.biooffice.rcp.product: Installation of product at.biooffice for environment win32/win32/x86_64 failed: Call to p2 director application failed with exit code 13. Program arguments were: [-metadataRepository, file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.rcp.product/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.rcp.product/target/targetPlatformRepository/, -artifactRepository, file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.rcp.product/target/,file:/resolution-context-artifacts@D%253A%255CWS18%255Cgit%255Cat.biooffice.rcp.product,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.rcp.product/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.feature/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.feature.admin/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.feature.free.addons/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.common.admin/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/lumo.core.runtime/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.osgi.service.dialog/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/lumo.osgi.service.notification/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.lookups/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.nls/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.querymanager/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/lumo.imports.xml.nls/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/jre.win32.win32.x86_64/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/lumo.osgi.service.multimedia/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/lumo.osgi.service.multimedia.impl/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/lumo.osgi.service.notification.impl/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/microsoftsqlserver/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/org.eclipse.gemini.dbaccess.microsoftsqlserver/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.osgi.service.dialog.impl/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.osgi.service.eclipselink/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.osgi.service.eclipselink.impl/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.bioobject/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.collection/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.contact/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.dataexchange/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.excursion/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.literature/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.multimedia/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.report/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.project/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.site/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.taxon/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.welcome/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.rcp/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.update/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.determination/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.attachedliterature/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.views.loan/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/com.mysql.jdbc/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/org.eclipse.gemini.dbaccess.mysql/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/lumo.exports.kml/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/lumo.exports.taxaendangered/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/lumo.exports.vcard/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/lumo.exports.shp/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/lumo.exports.mssql/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/lumo.exports.csv/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.osgi.service.map/target/,file:/D:/WS18/git/at.biooffice.osgi.service.map.impl/target/,file:/C:/Users/BlackPearl/.m2/repository/, -installIU, at.biooffice, -destination, D:\WS18\git\at.biooffice.rcp.product\target\products\at.biooffice\win32\win32\x86_64, -profile, DefaultProfile, -profileProperties, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, -roaming, -p2.os, win32, -p2.ws, win32, -p2.arch, x86_64]. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :at.biooffice.rcp.product
```

so all bundles build successfully but the product does not!
which referrs to: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu

by definition i had both org.eclipse.rcp and org.eclipse.e4.rcp as requirement. this leads to this error

i tried removing org.eclipse.rcp

also org.eclipse.e4.rcp

but in the end nothing works.

any ideas how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have an explicit dependency on the `org.eclipse.equinox.ds` plug-in. Current versions of Eclipse have dropped that plug-in and replaced it with the `org.apache.felix.scr` plug-in.

Comment: i need `org.eclipse.equinox.ds` for `org.eclipse.gemini` - so they replaced this with `org.apache.felix.scr` too?

Comment: I don't know anything about org.eclipse.gemini

Comment: i had a dependency in my configuration. though its compuling now, its no more working - but this is another story